# uws not found - VueJS using SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, fs

I'm trying to build a vue application using SocketIO. The first error I get on compiling ( fs not found ) is already fixed with adding: `node: { fs: 'empty' }` to my webpack.base.conf.js file.

But I have no idea how to fix the second error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 
This dependency was not found:
* uws in ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
```

Comment: Tried `npm install`? Please share `nodejs`, `npm` and `uws` versions

Comment: npm install doesn't change anything. Versions:  "uws": "^99.0.0", Node: v8.11.3 and npm: 5.6.0

Answer (score 4):

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
```

If you don't add "-client", you are using the server component. This won't work, as there is no "fs" on the browser, just on nodejs side.

To get typescript import to work, you need npm install of
`@types/socket.io-client`

Update:
Seems, that uws is not required for the client side. I could remove uws without running into errors. Will recheck that, if required...

Answer (score 0):

Seems `uws` package version has been deprecated, see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uws)

You can install other stable versions. Try below

```
$ rm -rf ./node_modules/uws
$ npm install uws@10.148.1 --save
```

**Update 1**

New versions with slightly different goal and purpose are available at https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js

Use of old releases is not recommended due to known bugs and problems.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the error. The app starts but it don't show it. Now I get this error: TypeError: exists is not a function. (In 'exists(filepath)', 'exists' is undefined)              It's not from a file written by me. Do you have an idea how to fix that ?

Comment: @mp_weber Can you share the code and `package.json`?

Comment: @mp_weber 
If you are using fs.exists
you can refer more here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: I posted the last code I added and my package.json . I normally don't use fs.exists but my console says something different at the moment.

Comment: @mp_weber Can you try
`$ rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`? keeping `"uws": "10.148.1"` in package.json

Comment: still not working. Same error but now I also get this:                                        WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings
These dependencies were not found:

* bufferutil in ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
* utf-8-validate in ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js

Comment: @mp_weber I will suggest posting a different question as It is not ok to extend a question with another question after initial answers have been posted.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers

Answer (score -1):

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "uws": "^10.148.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-10.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-socket.io": "^2.1.1-b"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.4.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.5",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.3.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.15",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8",
    "sinon": "^4.0.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.14.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "uglify-es": "^3.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

There is not much code yet. The last things i added was that:

```
    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          isConnected: false,
          socketMessage: ''
    } 
  },

  sockets: {
    connect () {
      // Fired when the socket connects.
      this.isConnected = true
    },

    disconnect () {
      this.isConnected = false
    },

    // Fired when the server sends something on the "messageChannel" channel.
    messageChannel (data) {
      this.socketMessage = data
    }
  },

  methods: {
    pingServer () {
      // Send the "pingServer" event to the server.
      this.$socket.emit('pingServer', 'PING!')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

After adding that I got all the errors.